# How to exclude kernel updates in Raspbian (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: kernel, debian, package, updates

I always use 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' in Raspberry Pi but I need to keep my kernel current version. I want to upgrade all packages except kernel ones. Is it possible? Can I use an option in this command?

Comment: I had a version kernel and I upgraded the followings packages and the kernel upgraded as well:

libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc
libraspberrypi0 raspberrypi-bootloader raspi-config wolfram-engine

Do all packages belong new kernel version?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent a package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold package_name
```

To cancel the hold, just run:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

I'm not sure, however, it's a good idea to do this with some packages. In your case, holding the kernel might prevent other packages from upgrading and would probably leave you without important system updates (security fixes come to my mind). So I'd think at least twice before doing that.